# QuickCheck prop to tasty prop

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

Im trying to go from from _prop example to write the same thing in Tasty.
(example from http://primitive-automaton.logdown.com/posts/142511/tdd-with-quickcheck)

```
game9_prop :: Game9 -> Bool
game9_prop = (9==) . length . unGame . unGame9
```

This is what I'm trying in tasty:

```
qcTestGengame9 :: TestTree
qcTestGengame9 = QC.testProperty "Better gen rate" $ 
   \ (g :: Game9) -> length . unGame . unGame9 g == 9 --ERROR LINE
```

This conversion gives me the following error:

```
test/Tasty.hs:53:11:
Illegal type signature: `Game9'
Perhaps you intended to use -XScopedTypeVariables
In a pattern type-signature
```

This is the type Game9:

```
-- To make generation rate better
newtype Game9 = Game9 { unGame9 :: Game }
   deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Arbitrary Game9 where
   arbitrary = (Game9 . Game) `liftM` replicateM 9 arbitrary
```

Comment: You need to add test groups,see https://github.com/feuerbach/tasty for an example

Comment: That comes later. The question is if the abowe prop translation is correct.

Comment: The point free style is probably wrong. Try something like `length $ unGame $ unGame9 g == 9`. Also it would be easier to help if you post the whole error message.

Comment: Did not help. I have added more information about the problem.

Comment: Did you already try to add the suggested pragma? `{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the immediate error, remove the type annotation, i.e., use

```
qcTestGengame9 :: TestTree
qcTestGengame9 = QC.testProperty "Better gen rate" $ 
   \ g -> (length . unGame . unGame9) g == 9
```

The expression `unGame9 g` already ensures `g :: Game9`.

But actually it's simpler: with `game9_prop` as defined, you can just use

```
qcTestGengame9 :: TestTree
qcTestGengame9 = QC.testProperty "Better gen rate" game9_prop
```